# 1-sparse recovery algorithm

Tags: algorithms, randomized-algorithms, streaming-algorithm

In the reference below, a 1-sparse recovery algorithm over a vector $a \in R^n$ is defined as follows. My question is why do we need the modulus (i.e. $x \mod p$)?

**Algorithm:**

1. Keep track of
   $$
      \begin{split}
      w_1 &= \sum a_i \\
      w_2 &= \sum i a_i \\
      w_3 &= \sum a_i z^i \mod p
      \end{split}
      $$
2. Test if
   $$
      \begin{split}
      w_3 \equiv w_1 \cdot z^{w_2 / w_1} \mod p
      \end{split}
      $$
   For some large prime $p$.

Reference: Section 3.2, "1-sparse recovery: second attempt", https://web.stanford.edu/class/cs369g/files/lectures/lec11.pdf

Comment: We encourage you to try to solve your question on your own before asking here, and to show us what progress you've made and where you got stuck.  Have you tried working through the proof to see if it works even without the mod $p$?

Comment: @D.W.♦, thank you for commenting. Why do we use mod $p$? For example, one explanation may be that the mod $p$ is used to enforce that we won't use more than $O(\log p)$ storage. Regarding your question, whether the proof works without the mod $p$, so as far as I see, it does. Actually my question is why the proof works *with* the mod $p$: In the last step, we check if $\sum a_i z^i - w_1 z^{w_2 / w_1} \equiv 0 \mod p$. If the difference in the LHS $= p$, then we'll mistakenly will consider the two terms in the LHS as equal.

Answer (score 1):

Without the mod p, the running time to check the condition would be exponential, which is unacceptable.  Also, it would require exponential space to store $w_3$ and to check the condition.

Also, the procedure involves choosing an integer $z$ uniformly at random from $\>0,\dots,p-1\}$.  You can choose an integer uniformly at random from $\{0,\dots,p-1\}$, but you can't choose it uniformly at random from the set of all integers.  So, you'd have to think about exactly what alternative approach you had in mind if you wanted to omit the mod p.